# AngularJS Validate Dropdown list based on Radio Button selection

Tags: angularjs, validation

I am using AngularJS and have a form with four radio buttons. Each radio button has dropdown lists that need to be updated if the radio button is selected. I have tried adding `ng-required="radioButton selected`. I want to disable the submit button if the dropdown lists are not selected based on the current radio button selection.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form name="schedulingForm" novalidate="">
      <div class="onePaddingBottom">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="radio col-md-2">
            <input type="radio" name="schedule" ng-change="GetOptions()" ng-model="model.LoadIntervalID" ng-value="1" ng-checked="scheduleType.Checked" />
            First of the Month
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="radio col-md-3">
            <input type="radio" name="schedule" ng-change="GetOptions()" ng-model="model.LoadIntervalID" ng-value="2" ng-checked="scheduleType.Checked" />
            Every Week on
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <select ng-model="model.StartWeekdayChosen" ng-options="weekday.Key as weekday.Value for weekday in model.weekdays" ng-required="model.LoadIntervalID==2"></select>
              Starting Previous
              <select ng-model="model.EndWeekdayChosen" ng-options="weekday.Key as weekday.Value for weekday in model.weekdays" ng-required="model.LoadIntervalID==2"></select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="radio col-md-3">
            <input type="radio" name="schedule" ng-change="GetOptions()" ng-model="model.LoadIntervalID" ng-value="3" ng-checked="scheduleType.Checked" />
            Every Month on the
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <select ng-model="model.WeekOfMonth" ng-options="timeOfTheMonth.Key as timeOfTheMonth.Value for timeOfTheMonth in model.timesOfTheMonth" ng-required="model.LoadIntervalID==3"></select>
            <select ng-model="model.WeekDayOfTheMonth" ng-options="weekday.Key as weekday.Value for weekday in model.weekdays" ng-required="model.LoadIntervalID==3"></select>
            of the month
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="setSchedule()" enabled="schedulingForm.$valid">Set Schedule</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
```

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/tCETo6DWQ63n6cakzok2?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have your own logic to determine when the button should be enabled, you need to have your own custom function that contains this logic.

This is the code that you need in your controller:

```
 var isValid = function (key, source) {
     for (var i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
         if (source[i].Key === key) {
             return true;
         }
     }

     return false;
 };

 $scope.isDisabled = function () {
     var selection = $scope.model.LoadIntervalID;
     if (selection === 1) {
         return false;
     } else if (selection === 2) {
         return !(isValid($scope.model.StartWeekdayChosen, $scope.model.weekdays) 
                && isValid($scope.model.EndWeekdayChosen, $scope.model.weekdays));
     } else if (selection === 3) {
         return !(isValid($scope.model.WeekDayOfTheMonth, $scope.model.timesOfTheMonth) 
                && isValid($scope.model.WeekOfMonth, $scope.model.weekdays));
     } else {
         return true;
     }
 };
```

While in your HTML, add a the `ng-disabled` directive to call the function that decides if the button should be disabled or not:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="setSchedule()" enabled="schedulingForm.$valid" data-ng-disabled="isDisabled()">Set Schedule</button>
```

[Working Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8M8tjVGjU98gpZa1FqRc?p=preview_)

Answer (score 0):

I think your validation is working correctly. You just need to change the code used to disable the button. Change the `enabled` attribute to `ng-disabled` and it will be disabled when the form is not dirty or the form is not valid.

```
<div class="text-center">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="setSchedule()" ng-disabled="!schedulingForm.$dirty || !schedulingForm.$valid">Set Schedule</button>
</div>
```

Working Plnker: http://plnkr.co/edit/iT7KIbR9gB7s5y7pfRaz?p=preview